FME 2023.1.2 Undo the last action
I am using FME 2023.1.2. I wanted to convert my geodatabase into geopackage in FME. I forgot to tick the overwrite option on my geopackage. And got my data duplicate in the geopackage. Google suggests to use the GIT reset but I don't want to risk it.
Do you have any suggestion to undo my last action or delete the duplicate data?

I don't think you can undo the committed transaction. The quickest way is to revert the file (if you have a backup?).

"Undo" isn't really a thing on bulk loading. Locate one pair of duplicates, and check whether deleting the last N features by ID would eliminate duplicates. Bulk loading is best done by script, because then you can restart the process from scratch if you mess up.
